# Converter arquivo XSD em classe c# no visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio

gostaria de saber como que eu faço para gerar uma classe c# baseado em um XSD no visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 1):

Abra um prompt do `DOS` e use a [ferramenta de definição de esquema](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-def-tool-gen) `XSD` com o caminho do arquivo `xsd` contendo o esquema:

```
> XSD arquivo.xsd
```